# How to integrate cisco CME by dial-peer to asterisk 11.19

Tags: asterisk, cisco

I have the enviroment that have an PSTN > GATEWAY (CME) . So I would like to know how to set the Asterisk to understand the dial-peer from the cisco. Somebody did this ?.

I did try to set the sip.conf to

```
[4000]
allowguest=yes
defaultuser=4000
nsecure=port,invite
bindport=5060
type=peer ; I did try change to "friend" as well, but the same problem.
port=5060
host=172.16.101.25
context=Plan1
insecure=yes
canreinvite=yes
qualify=yes
```

I did get a return from cisco.

```
<--- SIP read from UDP:172.16.101.25:53054 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.16.101.43:5060;branch=z9hG4bK0bfec330
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@172.16.101.43>;tag=as26306981
To: <sip:172.16.101.25>;tag=65E9F470-228A
Date: Thu, 22 Oct 2015 16:05:13 GMT
Call-ID: 100fe7696c5adbf3170c02ff799d7539@172.16.101.43:5060
Server: Cisco-SIPGateway/IOS-12.x
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Allow: INVITE, OPTIONS, BYE, CANCEL, ACK, PRACK, UPDATE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, REGISTER
Allow-Events: telephone-event
Accept: application/sdp
Supported: 100rel,timer,resource-priority,replaces,sdp-anat
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 170

v=0
o=CiscoSystemsSIP-GW-UserAgent 8815 8188 IN IP4 172.16.101.25
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 172.16.101.25
t=0 0
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 18 0 8 9 4 2 15
c=IN IP4 172.16.101.25
<------------->
--- (14 headers 7 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '100fe7696c5adbf3170c02ff799d7539@172.16.101.43:5060' Method: OPTIONS
```

The Cisco gateway send the REGISTER but asterisk don´t receive.

No firewalls or any rules.

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure the problem is on the Asterisk side, might be config missing on the cisco side.
If you want phone calls delivered from the cisco gateway to asterisk here is the config on the cisco side you need:

```
dial-peer voice 6000 voip
 destination-pattern 6...
 session protocol sipv2
 session target ipv4:172.16.101.43
```

This will send all 4 digit numbers starting with 6 to asterisk. Should be enough to get traffic flowing from cisco gateway to asterisk. Change `destination-pattern` to match the dial-plan on asterisk for the numbers you want delivered there. dot is a single digit wildcard, [] is used for collection of numbers to match.

If the gateway IOS is version 15 or later you will need to add the asterisk ip to the ip address trusted list also

```
voice service voip
 ip address trusted list
  ipv4 172.16.101.43
```

If you want/need to specify asterisk as a sip-ua on the cisco gateway you would do so under sip-ua in the cisco gateway config. This is where you would specify credentials used to register on asterisk. Here is a list of possible commands needed there.

```
sip-ua
 credentials username <username> password <password> realm <sip domain>
 authentication username <username> password <password> realm <sip domain>
 registrar ipv4:172.16.101.43
 sip-server ipv4:172.16.101.43
```

Comment: Don't answer off topic questions.